# Odoo Open Action on button click show breadcrumbs

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, breadcrumbs

I am trying to open a client action on a button click. When action opens it does not preserve breadcrumbs from where it is called.

```
<record id="view_dashboard_action" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">Rental Dashboard</field>
        <field name="tag">rental_availability</field>
        <field name="target">main</field>
    </record>
```

This is button code:

```
@api.multi
def action_open_rental_dashboard(self):
    action = self.env.ref('rental_management_v10.view_dashboard_action').read()[0]
    action['context'] = {'product_ids': [1,2,3]}
    action['flags'] = {'search_view': True, 'action_buttons': True},
    return action
```

I also tried with the target as 'current', but still no breadcrumbs.

Comment: `<field name="target">current</field>` should have worked. Did you re-install the module after modifying the XML?

Comment: @mingtwo_h9

I guess this doeson't work with client actions